# Not inserting right Cyrillic entry into MySQL database from Android application

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am currently developing an Android app that is using a remote MySQL database to write/read bookmarked by the user locations on the map. I acquire the address of a location via Reverse GeoLocation and after that pass it to a php file with the following code:

```
EditText addressEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressentry);
String address = addressEntry.getText().toString().trim();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address));
```

Here is my php file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head> 
<body>
    <?php
    $mysqlid = mysql_connect("XXX","XXX","XXX");
    mysql_select_db("XXX");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $mysqlid) ;

    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table123 (userid, address) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['userId']."', '".$_REQUEST['address']."') ");

    mysql_close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

If I submit an address that contains no-Cyrillic letters everything works fine - I get the record in the database. But if I submit a Cyrillic entry - I get the following record in the database :

```
.  13A
Sofia
```

Where every  (it's a rectangle-symbol but not shown here - copy-pasted appears like this - ?) is a letter from the actual address. Before submitting the address to the database I have a toast showing it and it appears to be valid and readable.[image: picture of the valid address shown]

Here is my code connecting the remote database:

```
public void onClick(View addBookmarkView) {
                InputStream is = null;

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userIdPassed));
                EditText addressEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressentry);
                String address = addressEntry.getText().toString().trim();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address));

                //http post
                try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PHP_URL);
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }
```

I am sure the error is not in my database nor the php file - the sql database it has an Collation set to utf8_general_ci and if I try to put a static Cyrillic entry via another php file it works fine. Here the example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head> 
<body>
    <?php
    $mysqlid = mysql_connect("XXX","XXX","XXX");
    mysql_select_db("XXX");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $mysqlid) ;

    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table123 (userid, address) VALUES ('123456789','асдсдасдас 123') ");

    mysql_close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this successfully adds a valid and readable in Cyrillic record in my database.

```
асдсдасдас 123
```

Do you have any idea if I miss to put something to specify encoding somewhere in the Android app code or maybe Manifest.xml or any other idea how to get this running? 
Cheers!

Comment: You should check how the actual request from Android looks like - when saving the data to SQL, add also this line - `file_put_contents("log.txt", print_r($_REQUEST,1));` and check the file contents afterwards - does the request data even includes the cyrillic characters or not. Probably it doesn't

Comment: Done this and here is the "log.txt" content:
`Array( [userId] => 1159448580 [address] => .   6 Sofia )`
On the place of empty spaces it has rectangles...
A screenshot - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/logfp.png/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the encoding for Cyrillic entries using this:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it appears not to be working - now I don't get even the non-Cyrillic letters saved - I have just an empty field in the database.